# Crontab scheduled backup not running

Tags: linux, backup, crontab

I need to have the ZIP compression happen on a different drive than the server due to limited space.

Here is the command is the line I use in crontab:

```
00 1 * * * osmc cd /media/SAMSUNG/backups/work/daily && zip -r -FS  Workdaily$(date +%a) /media/Data/Work
```

It should run daily at 1am, but it doesn’t. It seems to be caught up on the `cd /directory`.

If I run this manually it works fine.

Comment: I'd have cron simply run something like mybackup.sh and break my commands out within that script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your crontab command:

```
00 1 * * * osmc cd /media/SAMSUNG/backups/work/daily && zip -r -FS  Workdaily$(date +%a) /media/Data/Work
```

You state:

> If I run this manually it works fine.

So what this all means is the command works perfectly when you are logged in, but not in a `crontab` correct?

Well, look at your command. Specifically the `zip`. When you are logged into your system, the system knows to search your set paths—which are loaded *only* if you login—for the `zip` binary. But when you are running this as a `crontab` there are no search paths for binaries and such; you need to *explicitly* set the path to the `zip` binary.

So I would recommend running `which` to see where the `zip` binary is actually located like this:

```
which zip
```

The value returned should be something like this; this is where it is installed on my local Ubuntu 12.04 setup:

```
/usr/bin/zip
```

Do the same with `date` like so:

```
which date
```

And the output returned should be something like:

```
/bin/date
```

Now knowing that, adjust your `crontab` entry to explicitly call the full path to `zip` like this:

```
00 1 * * * osmc cd /media/SAMSUNG/backups/work/daily && /usr/bin/zip -r -FS  Workdaily$(/bin/date +%a) /media/Data/Work
```

And all should work fine.

That said, placing compound commands like that in a crontab—especially for a backup script—is back practice. The script might work, but in the end it becomes a tad cumbersome and confusing to maintain.

So I would recommend creating a simple Bash script with those commands inside of it and then running `crontab` on that Bash script. The contents of that Bash script could be something as simple as this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /media/SAMSUNG/backups/work/daily && /usr/bin/zip -r -FS  Workdaily$(/bin/date +%a) /media/Data/Work
```

Note I removed `osmc` since that is not a command; I believe it’s a reference to your user? So let’s say the Bash script is named `my_backup.sh` and is in your user directory named `/home/kris`. Then the new `crontab` entry would be:

```
00 1 * * * /home/kris/my_backup.sh
```

A setup like that is much easier to maintain in my humble opinion. And be sure that script is executable by running `chmod` on it like this:

```
chmod 744 /home/kris/my_backup.sh
```

Comment: Jake, I tried to manually start the crontab a minute in the future to test and it still did not run.

Here is my crontab entry to test:
28 19 * * * osmc /home/osmc/workdailybkup.sh
this was to run at 7:28pm EST.

Here is my script:
#!/bin/bash

osmc cd /media/SAMSUNG/backups/work/daily && /usr/bin/zip -r -FS  Workdaily$(date +%a) /media/Data/Work

The which zip was at the location you said it would be and the script is located at that path.

Comment: Sorry, I also chmod'd the script per your instructions.

Comment: If I try to run the script manually I get these errors as "sh" and "bash":
`osmc@osmc2:/media/SAMSUNG/backups/work/daily$ sh /home/osmc/workdailybkup.sh
: not foundworkdailybkup.sh: 2: /home/osmc/workdailybkup.sh:
/home/osmc/workdailybkup.sh: 3: /home/osmc/workdailybkup.sh: osmc: not found
osmc@osmc2:/media/SAMSUNG/backups/work/daily$ bash /home/osmc/workdailybkup.sh
/home/osmc/workdailybkup.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
/home/osmc/workdailybkup.sh: line 3: osmc: command not found`

Comment: Oh wow.... I forgot I left that in there! Good call! That is for crontab and shouldn't be in the bash script.

Comment: everything is working so far. I checked your first answer as correct. I am too new to upvote as of yet, sorry. Mistakes I made after your initial answer were leaving "osmc" in the bash that was the user for crontab only and creating the bash script in notepad. The notepad bash script returned a "r/" error which a quick google search told me to create in a UNIX/Linux format to correct. I used notepad++ personally. Thanks again for your help!